What is the purpose of <meta name="GENERATOR" content=""/>?
I am creating my HTML website, and I need to add this tag. Can we add this tag in my HTML website?

"and I need to add this tag." Why do you think you need to add this tag? Whoever told you you need to include is probably the source you should go to to find out what it is for and how to add it.
